# Add metadata to Objective-C methods and properties

Tags: objective-c, reflection

How can I add additional, custom information to my objective-c methods and properties?  I want to retrieve this metadata later on at runtime.

I know objective-c doesn't directly support method attributes, like in C#, but this is what I'm looking for:

```
[MyCustomAttribute(true)]
public void MyAwesomeMethod(int arg) {
     // ...
}
```

The closest thing I recently found was a `#define` in the UIKit header files called `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.  Apparently Apple tags certain methods with this to be read later on.

Methods and properties are then define like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

Can someone explain exactly how this works?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no inbuilt support for tagged metadata (attributes in .NET, annotations in Java, etc.) Apple's macro here is solely for the benefit of their developer tools, and you can't create your own that have any meaning past the preprocessor.

GCC/LLVM define some attributes that can be attached to various symbols. For instance, you can mark a method as deprecated by tagging it with `__attribute__((__deprecated__))` but there's still no way to make a meaningful custom attribute.

If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, maybe we can suggest an alternate approach to the problem.

Comment: I'm not trying to accomplish anything in particular at the moment.  Curiosity just got a hold of me. ;)

Comment: well LLVM has the required facilities AFAIK.. gcc of course not. You can even see that Metadata is compiled with the app. so is this answer outdated now?

Comment: Not yet. There's still no way to build and use the equivalent types in code.